# Check if wp_nav_menu items have submenus

Tags: menus, sub-menu, walker

I'm looking to output the following markup for a menu through wp_nav_menu,

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="/" aria-haspopup="true">Blog</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">JavaScript</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

The menu items may have submenus - if that's the case the top level link needs to be formatted as the example above. I've tried different solutions looking into the codex but without success. It seems I will need to create a walker for this unless I want to add a bunch of queries (running submenu loops inside a main loop). But since it's such a small change, wouldn't it be possible to add a filter hook onto the menu output instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want links with submenus to have an attribute of `aria-haspopup`. If this is correct, you should be able to do so using the `nav_menu_link_attributes` filter (WP 3.6 and above). You can also get around the necessity of having to write a custom Walker to check if an item has children by checking its css classes in the filter.

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'wpse154485_add_aria_haspopup_atts', 10, 3 );
function wpse154485_add_aria_haspopup_atts( $atts, $item, $args ) {
  if (in_array('menu-item-has-children', $item->classes)) {
    $atts['aria-haspopup'] = 'true';
  }
  return $atts;
}
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking that only IE 10+ will do anything with the aria-haspopup property?  i.e. another solution to handling hover with touch will have to be implemented for other browsers?

Comment: I just wanted to add that I've been searching for a while on how to add a button to expand submenu items after the anchor tag (for accordian menu). This code solved my problem if anyone else is interested. Just replace `$atts['aria-haspopup'] = 'true';` with `$args->after = "";`.