# wp_nav_menu: Is there a way to modify the output of <a> that got a submenu?

Tags: menus, walker

With some `preg_replace`, I can replace some classes in the `wp_nav_menu`, so one of my menu (which has submenu) now looks like this.

```
<li class="nav-item nav-item-has-children dropdown menu-publication show">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Publication</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="nav-item menu-book">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Book</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

However, I also need to replace the `<a>` element (the `.nav-link`) so that the `<a>` would look like this:

```
<a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" href="#">Publication</a>
```

Problem is, I only want to replace the anchor which has submenu. I don't want to meddle with `<a>` that got no submenu. I can't figure it out how to do this. Is there any idea?

Preferably without remaking the whole menu walker...

I'm thinking of doing this:

```
function change_submenu_link($submenulink) {    
    return preg_replace('/a class="nav-link"/','class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"',$submenulink);
}

add_filter('wp_nav_menu','change_submenu_link');
```

Problem is I don't know to make sure that it only replaces the `<a>` that got submenu. If there's a `has_submenu()` function maybe it could be handy.

Comment: Hi. Please share your current code, so we can add the necessary code to make it work the way you want.

Comment: @JackJohansson Added, I hope my question is clear enough. Not a native speaker here, having difficulties to explain what I meant....

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/154485/check-if-wp-nav-menu-items-have-submenus should provide insight on how to tell if a menu item has children

Comment: Just to note: the nav_menu_link_attributes filter, which the answer @mrben522 linked to uses, should also be used to change the classes. Editing the entire output using Regex should be avoided, when possible, since it's relatively slow.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [nav_menu_link_attributes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_link_attributes) to add attributes to links output by [wp_nav_menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) that have child/submenu links.

[wp_nav_menu conditionally assigns classes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#menu-item-css-classes) to links it outputs. You need to target links with the class *.menu-item-has-children*

You can add the attributes you want with the following filter/function:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'wpse270596_add_navlink_atts', 10, 3 );
function wpse270596_add_navlink_atts( $atts, $item, $args ) {
  if (in_array('menu-item-has-children', $item->classes)) {
    $atts['data-toggle'] = 'dropdown';
    $atts['aria-haspopup'] = 'true';
    $atts['aria-expanded'] = 'true';
  }
return $atts;
}
```